# How Do I Use Python To Add Images To An HTML File?

Tags: python, html

so I have some images I am attempting to have pop up on an html page when my for loop iterates over a word. Like a hieroglyph translation.

I have gone to my AIs for help but they did not succeed in clearing up my confusion.

Unfortunately, I am unsure on how it is that I write these images into an html page. To clarify, I understand that I need to use the .write() function, but I don't know what HTML to write.

Would it be something like this?

```
f.write("<html>")


f.write("<body>")


f.write(<img src=hierpglypha.png, "alt="MyHiero" width="500" height="377">)


f.write("</body>")


f.write("/html>")
```

BREAK

```
import webbrowser

mydict = {
    'a': 'eglypha.jpg',
    'b': 'eglyphb.jpg',
    'c': 'eglyphc.jpg',
    'd': 'eglyphd.jpg',
    'g': 'eglyph.jpg',
    'h': 'eglyphh.jpg',
    'i': 'eglyphi.jpg',
    'j': 'eglyphj.jpg',
    'k': 'eglyphk.jpg',
    'l': 'eglyphl.jpg',
    'm': 'eglyphm.jpg',
    'n': 'eglyphn.jpg',
    'o': 'eglypho.jpg',
    'p': 'eglypgp.jpg',
    'q': 'eglyphq.jpg',
    'r': 'eglyphr.jpg',
    's': 'eglyphs.jpg',
    't': 'eglypht.jpg',
    'u': 'eglyphu.jpg',
    'v': 'eglyphv.jpg',
    'w': 'eglyphw.jpg',
    'x': 'eglyphx.jpg',
    'y': 'eglyphy.jpg',
    'z': 'eglyphz.jpg',
    '1': 'eglyphTOP.jpg',
    '2': 'eglyphBOTTOM.jpg'
}

def egypt(x):
    #X is your name.
    myWord = "1"
    s = "" #HTML string to return
    for i in x: #saw this way of writing for loops in a lab. looked pretty nifty, so Im gonna use it
        if(x[i] != 'e' or x[i] != 'f'):
            myWord += x[i]
    myWord += "2"

    f.write("<html>")
    f.write("<body>")

    for i in myWord:
        f.write("<img src="+ mydict[myWord[i]])



    #TODO











    return s

#ask user for location of file to be created
plocation = input("Enter location: ")
#Create file
f = open(plocation, 'w')

name = input("Name: ")

#Write the HTML to the file
f.write(egypt(name))

#Close
f.close()

#Display it from within Python
webbrowser.open_new_tab(plocation)
```

Comment: what do you want? write to file? doesn't help if you just write the html content to the file?

Comment: So I'm trying to write several images to an html file so they will show up sequentially. But i am confused as to how to write an image into a html file

Answer (score 1):

Well, depends on your server type.

1. If serve as a web service server:

Just add below(make sure the image path is available)

```
<img src=hierpglypha.png, "alt="MyHiero" width="500" height="377">
```

2. If just wanna write the image data into file.

Use base64, code snippet below:

```
<img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....>
```

data after the base64, is the image base64 encode data.

Regarding the base64, there are many ways, you could get from some online site or python base64 package .etc

Comment: Im sorry, but I'm in a beginner's programming class, an I only understood about a fourth of that.

Comment: What do I add this to? <img src=hierpglypha.png, "alt="MyHiero" width="500" height="377">

Comment: Um...<img src="xxx"...> is standard html syntax, seems you better check html basic knowledge